# How to load a hash value for index.html?

Tags: url, hash, url-rewriting

I have my homepage set to appear on "www.website.com/index.html#home".

How can I make it so that "www.website.com/index.html#home" loads when the user simply types in "www.website.com"?

Comment: just edit your .htaccess file on your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use htaccess to rewrite
Or use index.php to header("location:index.html#home");